# Bat to copy all the jpg files from all the partitions to a location

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy

I am creating a batch file to copy all jpg files from all partitions to a usb drive (bat will be contained in the usb)....
I have figured out how to do that from one partition but can't figure out how to do that from all partitions as it wouldn't be obvious which drive letters to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play with

```
FOR %%P IN (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO IF EXIST
```